# Why does this array not get fouled up?

Tags: arrays

I'm studying code to learn about Extended USB Controls and I came across this bit of code shown below. The function reverses an array's order. It's pretty straight forward, except for one thing. Why doesn't the code corrupt the array? Using the source and destination as the same variable should corrupt it, shouldn't it?

```
/*
 * Convert a array of bytes from big endian to little endian and vice versa by inverting it
 */
static
uint8_t *raw_inv(uint8_t *data, int size) {

    int ai = 0;
    int bi = size - 1;
    uint8_t a = 0;
    uint8_t b = 0;

    while (ai < bi) {
        a = data[ai];
        b = data[bi];

        data[ai] = b;
        data[bi] = a;
        ai++;
        bi--;
    }

    return data;
}
```

Ah: It's the 'static' declaration, isn't it?

Comment: Where does it use the source and destination as the same variable? (the function's "static" declaration should have no effect on the copying.)

Answer (score 1):

It uses `a` and `b` as temporaries to hold the values it's exchanging. Only [one temporary is needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_(computer_programming)#Using_a_temporary_variable) -- this could be rewritten as:

```
while (ai < bi) {
    a = data[ai];
    data[ai] = data[bi];
    data[bi] = a;
    ai++;
    bi--;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I got it. Wow. It's really obvious. I thought they were writing a single location at a time, but they are literally swapping the locations.